# Count number of instances, and put them in a column while grouping by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I would like GROUP BY a certain column, and then count the number of instances a user has logged in during an interval.

Table

```
UserID | LoginDate  | LoginID
1      | 2013-01-03 | 100
1      | 2013-01-05 | 101
1      | 2013-02-04 | 102
2      | 2013-01-03 | 103
2      | 2013-01-05 | 104
2      | 2013-01-04 | 105
3      | 2013-01-03 | 106
3      | 2013-02-05 | 107
3      | 2013-02-04 | 108
```

Output

```
UserID | Between 2013-01-31 and 2013-02-31 | Between 2013-02-31 and 2013-02-28 
1      | 2 | 1
2      | 3 | 0
3      | 1 | 2
```

I have tried the following

```
select UserID, 
       count(case when LoginDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' then 1.0 else 0.0 end ),
       count(case when LoginDate between '2013-02-01' and '2013-02-28' then 1.0 else 0.0 end )
from Table
group by UserID
```

The problem I am getting is that the last two columns produce the same result as when I simply do count(LoginID).

Comment: where and how you are counting login_id in last two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SUM instead of COUNT i.e.:

```
select UserID, 
   sum(case when LoginDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31' then 1 else 0 end ),
   sum(case when LoginDate between '2013-02-01' and '2013-02-28' then 1 else 0 end )
from Table
group by UserID
```

...and I don't think you need to use decimals ie. ".0" shouldn't be necessary.